# ODBC universal way to get deleted rows in trigger

Tags: sql, database, odbc, ansi-sql

Is there any universal way to get the deleted/inserted/updated rows in trigger? I want to create one trigger (I mean one pice of code in my application), which should work on Oracle, Sql Server and Postgres. Is it possible? I'm using odbc drivers to connect to different dbs.

It's working in SQL Server, but not in Oracle.

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema.trg_nameON schema.table_name
                FOR DELETE
                AS
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @id BIGINT;

                    SELECT @id = d.ID
                    FROM deleted d

                    DELETE
                    FROM schema.table_name
                    WHERE TOP_ID = @id;
                END
```

Comment: and incidentally, this would bea very bad trigger in SQL server as it assumes that only one record is ever changed and that is a very poor assumption that you shoudl not make when writing a trigger. ANytimeyou havea a trigger in SQL server where you set a value for inserted or deleted to a scalar varaiable, the trigger is incorrect and needs to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, each RDMS will have its own syntax. The syntax you used is a sql server syntax.

what do you mean by create trigger on the application? Please provide us with more info

Comment: I'm creating application, which will check if some objects exists in different dbs. One of those objects is this trigger. I thought that I can create one piece of code, but i see it's not possible.